# Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor

Tags: apache

I am getting this error When i have Started the **apache server**

> Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd:
>   undefined symbol: apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error too this morning, it was a module conflict.

Removed the conflicting module, then ran easyapache 4 and reprovisioned the profile in WHM.

The conflicting module was:

> Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
>              cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
>              pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

```
         1. You have an upgrade for ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare-1.2.0-.5.47.x86_64 != ea-apache24-mod_cloudflare-1.2.0-.5.37.i686
```

Run yum update to see the error, or what ever command your OS has to check for updates.

Regards,
Tommy

Comment: I have updated the whm. Now My php file is displayed as a text. Any idea to fix this issues in whm

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with cPanel, check for updates via yum. In my case, updates were needed, so updated all yum packages.

I then found PHP scripts were not being parsed. Check that the PHP handler is set to whatever your handler should be. In my case, the handler was set to "None".

I hope this helps!